# String.Substring(...) Method Gives Exception

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I want to keep a string to another string strTotal from a richtextbox. then i want to split it into two SubString like firstPart and secondPart by a middle index say: midIndex.

Then I want to change some value in firsthalf and join with secondhalf. And finally show it to the richTextBox.

For this i used this code:

For my Last debug:

rtxtQueryPan.Text.Length = 53;
midIndex = 45;

```
 //string Totalqueryy = rtxtQueryPan.Text;
 string firstHalf = rtxtQueryPan.Text.Substring(0, midIndex-2); 
 string secondHalf = rtxtQueryPan.Text.Substring((midIndex- 1), (rtxtQueryPan.Text.Length - 1)); // THIS LINE SHOWS ERROR

 string duplicateFirstHalf = firstHalf;
 firstHalf += " " + clColumnNames.Text + ",";
 rtxtQueryPan.Text = firstHalf+secondHalf;
```

In the 3rd Line of the code says:

**Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length**

I have checked the length, midIndexvalue etc. But found no clue.

Comment: What are the values of `index` and `length`?

Comment: and what is the string you are using Substring on?

Comment: IIRC, the way substring works in c# you give .substring(startIndex, length).  So you'd want the second line to be rtxtQueryPan.Text.Substring((midIndex- 1), (rtxtQueryPan.Text.Length - 1 - midIndex ));  I believe that should work, I might have messed up the index though.

Comment: @decoyer Kindly mark something as the answer?

Comment: sorry @DavidPfeffer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C#'s `.Substring` function takes a **length**, not a **position** as its second argument.

Thus, you probably wanted to write the following code:

```
rtxtQueryPan.Text.Substring(midIndex-1, (rtxtQueryPan.Text.Length-1) - midIndex);
```

Also, the length argument is optional, and not something you should provide in your case, as you want the rest of the string included. You can also therefore write:

```
rtxtQueryPan.Text.Substring(midIndex-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Substring` can only work in the bounds of the string being acted upon. Here, `rtxtQueryPan.Text` refers to the text in the `RichTextBox` which is longer that the text currently held in the string. Remember the arguments of `Substring` are the start position and length.

You want `(rtxtQueryPan.Text.Length-1) - midIndex` as the second argument.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The function is `Substring` (lowercase "s"). :)

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. I got carried away hacking it out in this little editor. What would we do without intellisense now!? Thanks again :]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your grabbing the second string from the half way through and saying i want the entire string. if you use substring the second pramater is the length of your substring. this should fix it.
`string secondHalf = rtxtQueryPan.Text.Substring((midIndex- 1),
 (rtxtQueryPan.Text.Length - 1-midIndex));`